# How to use array[index] in source and target jsplumb+javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg, jsplumb

I have an array that has the id of two SVG elements stored at indexes `0` and `1`. I am using jsplumb to make a connector between the two elements and the code I am using is as follows:

```
jsPlumb.connect({
    source: divs[0], 
    target: divs[1]
});
```

`divs[0]` and `divs[1]` are the reference to array elements. The above code doesn't work and gives me the following error:

> jsPlumb.js:6203 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M 0 0 C -10 150 NaN NaN NaN NaN "

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about  `SVG` elements you have created rather than the `connect` method. Thus, it'd be better if you could share a fiddle.

Here is a working copy. I hope it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/mokarakaya/7c269fns/1/